# How to deploy multiple rails apps on one domain without symbolic links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger, mod-rails

According to the passenger documentation it is possible to deploy multiple rails apps on one domain by setting a central rails app and then link in other apps by creating symbolic links in the public directory of this app (and tell the webserver about it).

This is actually pretty messy. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour just with the webserver configuration? I am using apache2 with mod_rails.

What i want is the following:

myapp.subdomain.domain.tld
myapp.subdomain.domain.tld/staging
myapp.subdomain.domain.tld/development

Where each of the URLs point to a different rails project which reside in the following directories on the server:

/var/www/myapp/production/current/public
/var/www/myapp/staging/current/public
/var/www/myapp/development/current/public

In this scenario i would need to place the symbolic links in the public folder of the production folder, which is not what i want (it feels very dirty). It might even be that these projects will later reside on different servers.

Comment: Do you not want to use virtual hosting instead?  Each app could have a different subdomain, and it's very easy to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to enable mod_alias and use alias directive to map different locations
myapp.subdomain.domain.tld will map by default to the location as defined in the document root
then 
for myapp.subdomain.domain.tld/staging
use the directive

```
Alias staging /var/www/myapp/staging/current/public
```

for myapp.subdomain.domain.tld/development
use the directive

```
Alias development /var/www/myapp/development/current/public
```

For further informations, take a look at the following mod_alias doc : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/urlmapping.html